# Getting inputs and replace these data in existed file

Tags: java, file

I wanted to get some input with a GUI and save it in a file that I created before in another `JFrame`. But the input that the program got from the `JTextField` couldn't be replaced in the file and the file doesn't change.
the file saved like this:

```
000,THR,000000000000,00
```

(with the repetition 10,000 times)

I want to replace the data with the input in the correct order depending on the `acc_num`. But other lines stay in the current order.

This is my code:

```
public void save_account_info() 
{
    try
    {
        Path account = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\lotus\\Desktop\\Java\\project\\account.txt");
        FileChannel fcIn = null;
        fcIn = (FileChannel)Files.newByteChannel
                (account, CREATE, WRITE);
        
        String acc_num = jTextField2.getText();
        Integer.parseInt(acc_num);
        
        String branch_name = jComboBox1.getName();
        
        String balance = jTextField6.getText();
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(balance);
        String customer_num = jTextField3.getText();
        
        String delimiter = ",";
        String s = acc_num + delimiter + branch_name + delimiter +
                df.format(balance) + delimiter + customer_num +
                System.getProperty("line.separator") ;
        
        byte data[] = s.getBytes();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
        fcIn.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       System.err.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please consider reading [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I don't see **where** you write the bytes back to the FileChannel. Have a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-filechannel), there are a few examples on how to handle FileChannels. If you want to replace the text you may have to get the position of the text in the file and then write the new text at that position. Something like `fcIn.write(buffer, textPosition)` maybe? And just a tip: `Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Something went wrong when saving the file", ex);` in your "catch" will give you more details on any exceptions.